# Navigation buttons always lead to the last page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have created a pagination system using JavaScript using the following code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= last_page; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerText = i;
  paginationButtons.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener('click', () => changePageNumber(i));
}
```

This code creates the correct buttons.

The problem is if I click on any one of these buttons, the program will always navigate to the last page. Why is this and how can I cause the program to always navigate to the correct page.

Comment: Use `for (let i = 1;`

Comment: I have done that

Comment: You have `for (i = 1;`. Are you sure you added `let`?

Comment: I forgot to do that. This is working correctly now. Thanks